# When adding a -c option to a Ghostscript command the printer popup appears even though it has been suppressed

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Consider the following ghostscript command invoked form the command line on windows.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2  -dORIENT1=false -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dFIXEDMEDIA -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=398 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=157 -dNOPAGEPROMPT -dQUIET -dNumCopies=1 -sOutputFile="\\spool\BWLAB05" "c:\print\download\133679.pdf"
```

This command works great. The print comes out and there is no pop up box. Now I add the following.

```
-c "<</Orientation 2>>setpagedevice"
```

to the above command to make

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -c "<</Orientation 2>>setpagedevice" -c "quit"  -dORIENT1=false -dNOPROMPT -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dFIXEDMEDIA -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=398 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=157 -dNumCopies=1 -sOutputFile="\\spool\BWLAB05" "c:\print\download\133679.pdf"
```

the print window appears. I have changed no other part of the command. What is causing this to happen? How can I stop the print window appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of operands to Ghostscript is important. Especially when using the `-c` switch, which introduces PostScript to be executed.

Effectively you are running two commands here:

```
-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -c "<</Orientation 2>>setpagedevice" -c "quit"  

-dORIENT1=false -dNOPROMPT -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dFIXEDMEDIA -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=398 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=157 -dNumCopies=1 -sOutputFile="\\spool\BWLAB05" "c:\print\download\133679.pdf"
```

As soon as it hits the `-c` Ghostscript stops processing the command line, and runs the PostScript. At this point we have not yet encountered the `-dNOPROMPT`, **and** as you haven't (yet) set the printer, Ghostscript doesn't know what printer to use so , unsurprisingly, the printer popup appears.

Ghostscript carries on processing the remainder of the command line as PostScript until it reaches a `-f`, or in fact any switch beginning `-`. You haven't put a -f in there, but I would very strongly recommend that you do. You also don't need to put a secopnd `-c`, once you've started processing the command line as PostScript it continues, until you stop it. I also suspect that you really don't want the `quit` in there. That terminates the interpreter, which means the changes you've introduced via setpagedevice will be discarded, because the interpreter returns to the default state.

After processing the content of the `-c`, Ghostscript carries on and processes the remainder of the command line. This time there's a `-dNOPROMPT` so you don't get prompted.

I would expect that this:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dORIENT1=false -dNOPROMPT -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOSAFER -q -dFIXEDMEDIA -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=398 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=157 -dNumCopies=1 -sOutputFile="\\spool\BWLAB05" -c "<</Orientation 2>>setpagedevice" -f "c:\print\download\133679.pdf"
```

would work much better. Note your initial command line has a duplicate NOPAUSE and specifies both NOPROMPT and NOPAGEPROMPT (you don't need NOPAGEPROMPT if you set NOPROMPT, and you don't need either if you set NOPAUSE).

Finally I would **urge** you not to use `-dNOSAFER`, while it currently has no effect (because that's the default setting) we will soon be making SAFER the default and setting `-dNOSAFER` will substantially reduce your security when running files.

You should really use `-dSAFER` right now. There are a number of CVEs against this, and proof of concepts circulating right now which can have undesirable effects on your computer (running arbitrary executables, opening, writing, deleting files etc) if you **don't** use `-dSAFER`. If you don't know why you want `-dNOSAFER`, then use `-dSAFER` instead.

Oh, you should also upgrade to the current version, 9.27, the version you are using is  a year old.